# Validate field value against another with arrays in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

> I want to validate min value in array validation against another value
>   in this array in Laravel MVC

## Current Rules

`$rules['criteria.*.inputOne'] = 'required|numeric';
$rules['criteria.*.inputTwo']='required|min:criteria.*.inputOne';`

## Needed Rules

I want to use `criteria.*.inputOne` in min validation in `$rules['criteria.*.inputTwo']`

Comment: your question is not clear enough [see how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

## I find this solution to my problem:-

```
$rules['criteria.*.inputOne']='required|gt:criteria.*.inputTwo';
```